Hoeffding inequality for a product of two random variables
Let $X_1,X_2, \dots, X_{m_1}$, $Y_1,Y_2, \dots, Y_{m_2}$ be $m_1 + m_2$ independent random variables from a probabilistic space $\mathcal{X}$, let $h: \mathcal{X} \to \{-1,1\}$
I'm interested in point estimation: $\mu = \underset{x,y \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{E}}[h(x)h(y)]$.
The estimation takes the form $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{m_1m_2} \sum_{i=1}^{m_1} \sum_{j=1}^{m_2} h(X_i) h(Y_j)$
Is there a generalized Hoeffding inequality to measure concentration for this (Two-sample U-statistic) setting?

Hoeffding just requires bounds on the summands, so couldn't you use the fact that $h(X_i)h(X_j) \in [-1, 1]$ by definition? Or are you looking for something more specific than a bound of the form $P(\hat{\mu} - \mu > \varepsilon)$?

@chang_trenton I'm looking for a tight upper bound for $\mathbb{P}[|\hat{\mu} - \mu| \leq \epsilon ]$
